# Re-writing "Everybody loves somebody" and variants in symbolic logic.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Right now I'm working on a set of questions and I came across a two-parter that confused me a bit with the way it was asked. The question is simply put as such:

```
Write the statements below in symbolic logic.
   a. Everybody loves somebody.
   b. Somebody loves everybody.
```

Would the way to rewrite this be a simple as using existential and universal quantifiers? Such that a. would be translated to

"∀x, where x is a person, ∃ person x they love."

And b. would be translated to

"∃x such that x loves ∀x."

Is this a proper way to answer the question? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to define $L(x,y)$ to mean that $x$ loves $y$

Comment: Another problem that been hasn't mentioned with your formulation: you reuse variables, which is a Very Bad Idea.  (In particular, in general your sentences wouldn't be considered syntactically correct.)

Comment: Here's an obligatory cartoon on this very issue: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-04-19/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right ideas, basically, but there is some more work to get the statements into symbolic logic.

Let $L(x,y)$ be the relation "$x$ loves $y$". Then we get:

$$a.\quad ∀x \, ∃y \, L(x,y)$$

$$b.\quad ∃x \, ∀y  \, L(x,y)$$

(The exact punctuation depends on the logical system.)

Comment: Ah so by defining a variable L(x,y) I can essentially skip the unneeded wordy answer I originally came up with?

Comment: @JohnathanScott: Yes. In fact, such a relation (not a "variable": $x$ and $y$ are variables) is needed to use actual symbolic logic. The "wordy" forms are only half-way there.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "everybody loves somebody" can be translated to "every person x loves some person y" but notice that I said "Person" therefore you have to declare that x and y are both a person.
The correct translation would be:
∀∃(P(x)^P(y))->L(x,y) 
And if you were to translate this to a language that makes more sense to a computer you would say "for every x and some y, such that x and y are a person (not saying they are equal or different) there is an x that loves y"